# public void onButtonClick (View v ) v подсвечиваеться красным

Tags: android-studio

Пишу на  Android Studio

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
  public void onButtonClick  (View "------->" v "<--------" )
//Стрелок и кавычек нет
{

EditText el1= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num1);
        EditText el2= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num2);
        EditText el3= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num3);
        EditText el4= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num4);
        TextView resText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Rest);
        int ch1= Integer.parseInt(el1.getText().toString());
        int ch2= Integer.parseInt(el2.getText().toString());
        int st1 = Integer.parseInt(el3.getText().toString());
        int st2 = Integer.parseInt(el4.getText().toString());
        int a= (ch1 * st1);
        int b= (ch2 * st2);
        int c= (a+b)+10;
        resText.setText(Integer.toString(c));
    }
```

Comment: И вопрос, зачем методу View ? Он там не нужен, для инициализации EditText и TextView. И в целом, вы всё не правильно делаете. Поищите в интернете курсы для ознакомления программирования в среде Android Studio.

Comment: Android Studio - это IDE, а пишите вы на Java. А судя по вашему коду, вы нарушаете синтаксис языка, о чём вам и говорит IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Методы не должны быть внутри других методом, их нужно размещать внутри класса.

```
public class ExampleClass extends AppCompatActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        onButtonClick();
    }

    public void onButtonClick(){
        EditText el1= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num1);
        EditText el2= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num2);
        EditText el3= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num3);
        EditText el4= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num4);
        TextView resText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Rest);
        int ch1= Integer.parseInt(el1.getText().toString());
        int ch2= Integer.parseInt(el2.getText().toString());
        int st1 = Integer.parseInt(el3.getText().toString());
        int st2 = Integer.parseInt(el4.getText().toString());
        int a= (ch1 * st1);
        int b= (ch2 * st2);
        int c= (a+b)+10;
        resText.setText(Integer.toString(c));
    }
}
```